# error during execution of application using GpsPositionRequest class

Tags: symbian

i'm caught in a problem.
i'm developing an application based on lbs and referred the code given in (forum.nokia.com/wiki) GpsPositionRequest.zip
when i try to install the app on device it gets installed successfully but while executing it shows error "unable to execute for security reasons"..
i've signed the sis file using carbide C++.
my mmp file include the capabilities:
ReadDeviceData,
WriteDeviceData,
Location,
NetworkServices,
ReadUserData.

my class uses TPositionInfo,RPositionServer,RPositioner 
does it need any other capability??
(i'm using carbide c++ and s60 3rd edition fp1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Location` is the capability you need.

What kind of signing key/cert are you using? Does it have the required capabilities?

---

Updated after comments: In 3rd edition FP1 the Location capability is a system capability that cannot be granted with a self-signed certificate. (It became a user capability that works with self-signed cert in Symbian OS 9.3 i.e. FP2.)

Comment: I use self signing. How can I know what kind of signing is required by the capability?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer: see this page: http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Capabilities_%28Symbian_Signed%29